# find doesn't give me output when trying to find certain files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want find these files :

- smart users04.csv
- smart users07.csv

when I enter this:

`find . -type f  -regex  "\bsmart\susers\d{2}\.csv\b"`

It returns with nothing

Comment: Only the \b is valid for any of find's regextype's; \s and \d aren't in any of them, as far as I can see in the GNU find info pages.

Comment: Also see [How to tell find command to escape space characters in file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42483587/608639), [How do I use find when the filename contains spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81349), [How can I search for files in directories that contain spaces in names, using “find”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25363070/608639), [find with spaces in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12646124/608639), etc.

Comment: @Roadowl is there any way to match these file names? I tried Grep but It took long time

Comment: `find . -type f -regex ".*smart.users..\.csv"`

Comment: Or, alternatively: `find . -type f -regex ".*smart.users[0-9][0-9]\.csv"`.

Comment: Or: `find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*smart.users[[:digit:]]{2}\.csv"`.

Comment: Or even `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended  -regex '.*\bsmart users[0-9]{2}\.csv\b'` ;D ... interesting point is that even **if** any of the regextypes knew \d it would still fail because as a minimum output there's always the leading `./`, which doesn't match the wordboundry requirement.

Comment: Actually, my previous can be shorter: `find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*smart.users[[:digit:]]{2}.csv"`.

Comment: @tink actually the word boundary worked with your  example it matched with
smart users04.csv and smart users07.csv  but didnt match with ssmart users09.csv

Comment: also `find . -type f -regex ".*\bsmart.users[0-9][0-9]\.csv\b"` worked with the word boundary

Comment: @SamNano, well, yes. But it **won't** work without the `.*` before the word boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments to question ;)

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\bsmart\s+users[0-9]{2}\.csv\b'
```

Comment: `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\bsmart users[0-9]{2}\.csv\b" | cut -c  3-`

that will give me result beginning from smart without `./ `

Comment: @SamNano  Or, instead of invoking a second tool, just do `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*\bsmart users[0-9]{2}\.csv\b"  -printf "%f\n"`  =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*smart users..\.csv"
```

or:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*smart.users[[:digit:]]{2}.csv"
```

or even:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*smart users[[:digit:]]{2}.csv".
```